# How to search the loan no in text table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This my view page:
[image]
In this page i have text box "search".if i enter the loan no in that box it should be filter and give that loan no only using javascript.

This javascript code is  working for only html table but i want in text box table.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  var input = $("#myInput").val();
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = $("#tb3").val();
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
}

table th {
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb3">
  <tr>
    <th>Unique ID</th>
    <th>Random ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="214215"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="442"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="1252512"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="556"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="2114"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4666"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="3245466"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="334"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24111</td>
    <td>54364</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please remove all PHP from the HTML part to make a [mcve]. This question is not relevant to codeigniter nor PHP

Comment: Also why not use jQuery all the way?

Comment: that i changed the table name now'

Comment: A table does not have a value. This statement does not make any sense `var table = $("#tb3").val();`

Comment: please change it in jquery itself

Comment: Please add HTML to the snippet. I am not going to copy your code and install codeigniter to test your code.

Comment: @mplungjan http://jsfiddle.net/k0nt6dau/ use this example

Comment: It would be very much more efficient to add the loan number as an attribute of the row, then you can very easily find the required row so show and hide the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use jQuery all the way

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
  var filter = String(this.value).toUpperCase();
  var $rows = $("#tb3 tbody tr");
  if (filter) {
    $rows.each(function() {
      $tr = $(this);
      $tr.hide();
      $(this).find("input").each(function() {
        if (this.value.indexOf(filter) != -1) { // === 0 if filter match from start
          $tr.show()
        }
      })
    })
  }
  else {
    $rows.show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Random ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="214215"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="442"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1252512"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="556"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="2114"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4666"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="3245466"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="334"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

If the ID is static, make it part of the row:

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
  var val = this.value.toUpperCase()
  $("#tb3 tbody tr").each(function() {
    var id = String($(this).data("id"));
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(val) != -1) // use === 0  to match from start
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Random ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="214215">
      <td><input type="text" value="214215"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="442"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="1252512">
      <td><input type="text" value="1252512"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="556"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2114">
      <td><input type="text" value="2114"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4666"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="3245466">
      <td><input type="text" value="3245466"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="334"></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

Comment: @Tom. Please see update. It will work regardless of format

Comment: In first code if i enter the value 1 it shows the value for starting 1 but when i entered 2 it doesn't shows the value of 2 in my browser

Comment: you can remove the last line

Comment: hi @Tom, Stack Overflow is not a debugging community, I think all our answers can help you get started.

Comment: @Tom Fixed my scripts

Comment: @RobG try again

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `hidden` attribute to filter out `non-matches`.

```js
const filterTable = (value = '') => document
  // get all `#tb3` table rows (tr)
  .querySelectorAll('#tb3 tr')

  // for each row in `#tb3` table
  .forEach((row) => {
    if (!value) {
      // if value is empty (''), make the row visible and exit.
      row.hidden = false;
      return;
    }
    
    // get the input field of the first `td` of the current row (tr)
    // it would be easier if you would assign a class name to the input
    const input = row.querySelector('td:first-child input');
    
    // pick `input.value` from the `td` (or default to an empty string)
    const loanNo = ((input || {}).value || '').trim();

    // make the row visible if the `td input.value` matches our query, otherwise hide it
    row.hidden = loanNo != value;
    
    // you can change the matching algorithm by looking at my end notes below
  });


document
  .querySelector('#search')
  .addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => filterTable(target.value));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha256-Nfu23DiRqsrx/6B6vsI0T9vEVKq1M6KgO8+TV363g3s=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>

<tr />

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Loan No</th>
      <th>Party Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input value="100" class="form-control" /></td><td>Republican</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="250" class="form-control" /></td><td>Democrat</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="1000" class="form-control" /></td><td>Green</td></tr>    
    <tr><td><input value="120" class="form-control" /></td><td>Pirats</td></tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

1. Match is being performed as `exact`, but you can always use `loanNo.includes(value)` or `loanNo.startsWith(value)` depending on your needs.

Comment: Hello i asked in should in textbox not simple html table

Comment: because mine is just a minimal reproducible example... the other ths and tds are not necessary for the sake of the example...

Comment: if it possible or not?

Comment: yes, my code gets the `input.value` of each `first td` in each `tr`

Comment: how? i get  header value?

Comment: I added some comments to explain what's going on in the snippet. hope it helps :)

Comment: what i asked what you said?